# Prove or disprove the following statement: If $ \sum a_{n} $ convergent,then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (n \cdot a_{n})=0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question :** Let  $a_{n} \ge 0$. Prove or give a counter example the following statement: If $ \sum a_{n} $ is convergent,then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (n \cdot a_{n})=0 $

I believe that limit comparison test is necessary but I'm not sure how to use it here, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Hint: this isn't true. For a counterexample, consider a sequence which contains many zeros...

Comment: Can you maybe explain me it a little bit more detailed?

Comment: I'll give an example and leave it for you to check it works. Consider $a_n$ such that $a_{2^k}=1/2^n$ and $a_n=0$ for other $n$...

Comment: Is the new edit what you meant to say. (I edited beacause I believe you want to say this, and may be example given by @Wojowu is no more counter example{I am talking about first comment.})

Comment: I quoted my book, the mathematical context was correct, but the language part is questionable.

Comment: @Zauberkerl What is the language of your book?

Comment: it's from a Slovakian book from one of my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For another counterexample, consider with $m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n}, \,\,\,\, n = m^2, \\ \frac{1}{n^2}, \,\,\, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then $\liminf na_n = 0 \neq 1 = \limsup na_n,$ and $\sum a_n$ is convergent since

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n = \sum_{n = m^2, \, 1 \leqslant n \leqslant N}\frac{1}{m^2} + \sum_{n \neq m^2, \, 1 \leqslant n \leqslant N}\frac{1}{n^2} \leqslant 2 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2}$$

You might try proving the statement for the case of $a_n$ nonincreasing, where it is true.